# Hibernate Tool for Weblogic 9.2.1

Tags: hibernate

I'm using weblogic **workshop 9.2.1** . Is there any **hibernate tool** available which is supported by weblogic workshop 9.2.1 ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of eclipse your IDE is based on but weblogic is based on eclipse. You could always try installing the Hibernate tools based on instructions at [this](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/setup.html) link

Comment: Thanks for the info. My eclipse version is 3.1.2 . But this site contains hibernate tool for Eclipse 3.2.x based Eclipse IDE. Do you have any suggestions on this ?